# Google API for the Search Result Events

Tags: events, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-search-api

I'm looking for the correct API for the events that show up in a regular Google Search, the ones that are structured (with name, datetime, location)

Any help or guidance is appreciated

I have tried the Custom Search with no luck, and also the Calendar API (which seems to require a calendar ID, more so for personal calendars or targeted public ones)

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look - while I didn't find a fully programatic API yet, here are two things that can get you started on more:

- How to search the events page directly: use the following URL schema: `https://www.google.com/search?q=cool+conferences&oq=cool+conferences&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn` - replacing "cool+conferences" with any string you like - this can let you create dynamic URLs for event searches.
- How to access event metadata for a given page - google is pushing a standard to structure data on webpages to support "smart" searches such as for events. They are using a data structure called JSON-ld. [More details](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event#guidelines). If you want to read such metadata from a webpage, here is one **scraper** I have found that does that - [extruct](https://github.com/scrapinghub/extruct) (though I didn't get a change to test it yet).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

We've actually just made an API to scrape the Google event results. You can query it directly like this:

```
https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_events&q=Events+in+Austin
```

Or if you are using Ruby, you can do something like this:

```
require 'google_search_results' 

params = {
  engine: "google_events",
  q: "Events in Austin",
}

client = GoogleSearchResults.new(params)
events_results = client.get_hash[:events_results]
```

Some documentation: https://serpapi.com/google-events-api

Comment: but this is a paid version it cost $50 a month for 5000 searches

Comment: Any updates here for free alternatives or something official from google maybe?